# Rails + Zurb - How to Priorize My Css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, rubygems, overriding

I want to override some properties from the css generated by Zurb Gem. The problem is that there is no link at the application to include these files. So if I put `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>` it will load before the hidden css files created by the gem. What can I do to solve that issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the new asset pipeline system from Rails since 3.1 version. You can define the order of you loading in your application.css. The order define inside is maintain.

So by example you can do

```
/*
 * = require 'foundation'
 * = require 'my_css'
 * = require 'my_hack_of_foundation
 */
```

Of if you use the css in application.css you can require in last of your file

```
/*
 * = require 'foundation'
 */

body {
  background: black;
}

/*
 * = require 'my_hack_of_foundation
 */
```

Comment: I ran into load order issues also and opted to remove require_tree in favor of manually loading what I needed. I would opt for the first example, I prefer to leave code out of application.js|css files.